# Correctly configuring selenium-webdriver geckodriver on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: node.js, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, path

I'm doing a particular scraping job with selenium on node, and the code runs successfully on my local mac. However, I'm trying to do the same on a demo Google Compute vm instance and I'm not sure how to configure the geckodriver correctly. Can someone please guide me?

This is the output I get:

```
/home/dee_m316/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ELF
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dee_m316/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:32:17)
```

The code is fine, but I feel its trying to read my geckodriver as a file instead of a executable or some such issue. Its either that or its not on my path.

code/

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
var sleep = require('sleep');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

  const screen = {width: 640, height: 480}; //size of headerless browser
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(new firefox.Options().headless().windowSize(screen)).build(); //for headerless mode
```

My OS is a `Ubuntu 18.04.`

`My code runs in the /home/dee_m316/j.js` #directory
There's a geckodriver at the same level as the script as well as copied to:

```
/home/dee_m316/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/geckodriver
/home/dee_m316/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox
/home/dee_m316/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.exe
```

I've tried:

```
export PATH="$PATH":/home/dee_m316/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/
```

and

```
node j.js --binary /home/deep_m316/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.exe
```

but the error is the same. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`firefox.exe` is the name of the Firefox binary built for *Windows*...  you are trying to run it on a Linux system.

The solution is to use the appropriate versions of Firefox and geckodriver for your platform.

Comment: What would it be for ubuntu? Could you please share? Given I'm new and that I've the same file named as 'geckodriver', 'firefox', and 'firefox.exe' all in the same path accessible directory, it should choose any of these- whatever works. But it clearly isn't using any of these, meaning the filetype is wrong or its not finding it for some reason. What need I do here?

Comment: it doesn't try every driver and use "whatever works".. once it tries an invalid binary, it dies.  For Ubuntu, you would want to download the Linux package that matches your system.. so either the linux32 or linux64 tarball from geckodriver's release page.  for example, see: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.23.0